# Clustering of Variables around Latent Variables (CLV) over only qualitative data

Tags: r, clustering, hierarchical-clustering

I'm reaching out today because I have a concern regarding the clustering approach employed with the CLV method introduced by Vigneau and Qannari in 2003. I've noticed that this method is predominantly utilized in quantitative analysis. Furthermore, there is an R library named ClustVarLV associated with its implementation, which you can find more details about here: [Link to ClustVarLV documentation](https://journal.r-project.org/articles/RJ-2015-026/RJ-2015-026.pdf). However, in both the original papers, I couldn't find any mention of its application to categorical variables.

My specific investigation involves a substantial number of variables related to entrepreneurial activities, which are represented as a group of one-hot encoded variables (dummies). Regrettably, I haven't come across any information in the literature regarding the use of categorical variables with the CLV method.

The paper does describe a technique used in Multiple Correspondence Analysis proposed by Saporta in 1990, involving a transformation G ̃ = GD−1/2, where D represents the diagonal matrix containing the relative frequency of each category. This approach is employed to cluster both qualitative and quantitative data. However, I'm uncertain whether it's suitable for exclusive use in qualitative clustering.

Could you please advise whether I can utilize Saporta's approach in this scenario, or if there's another preferred method that would be more suitable for my needs?

Thank you for your assistance!!!!!!